# Setting UINavigationBar font using UIAppearance stopped working with iOS 13.4 SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am setting my app's navigation bar font from `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`, using this code:

```
let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: navTitleColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .medium)]
```

This was working what I was using Xcode 11.3, but now that I have upgraded to Xcode 11.4, it no longer works for iOS 13 devices.  I have also tried using the new appearance API `let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()`, but I'm getting the same results.   How can I get this to work again?

Comment: Same issue here, nothing I've tried fixes it. Have you reported it to Apple via the Feedback Assistant yet?

Comment: @TheJeff
Have a look at my answer, It works fine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60902418/navigation-bar-title-font-problem-on-ios-13/60903234#60903234

Comment: Yes, I have submitted a bug report.  Anyone else who has the same problem should do so too, to let Apple know it’s important.