# Navigation Bar title font problem on ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11.4

I’m using Xcode 11.4 and iOS 13.4.
I have set navigation bar title custom font using UINavigatinBar.appearance()
And it works correctly but on iOS 13+ when i try to push to another VC and then comeback to the parent VC, the parent VC title font suddenly  has been set to default font and after a second it changes back to the custom font.

Below is a gif of the problem:

[nav bar font problem](https://giphy.com/gifs/jqfTFTGgy5EbJhjUJi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS 13.+ has `UINavigationBarAppearance` approach to customize NavigationBar-Title & NavigationBar-BarButtonItems

Check this code, might help you

```
    let titleFontAttrs = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "custom-font-name", size: 20)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white ]
    let barButtonFontAttrs = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "custom-font-name", size: 14)! ]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white // bar icons

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .red // If you want different nav background color other than white

        appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleFontAttrs
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = titleFontAttrs // If your app supports largeNavBarTitle

        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

        appearance.buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = barButtonFontAttrs
        appearance.buttonAppearance.highlighted.titleTextAttributes = barButtonFontAttrs

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red // bar background

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = titleFontAttrs

        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonFontAttrs, for: .normal)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(barButtonFontAttrs, for: .highlighted)
    }
```

Comment: Weird, I'm using iOS 14 & Xcode 12, above code is not take effect at all.

Comment: That's strange, I've defined the above in `UINavigationController` extension

Comment: @Noor facing same issue with xCode12 and iOS 14

Comment: @pawan_kumar the navigationBar background is not changing for you or the bar button attributes? Or both?

Comment: @Noor I was checking only navigation title. I used  UILabel.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go, manage it in viewDidAppear:

```
let lblTitle = UILabel()

let titleAttribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 21),
                                                .foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Navigation Title", attributes: titleAttribute)

lblTitle.attributedText = attributeString

lblTitle.sizeToFit()
navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly.
BTW do you know why the other approach doesn't work suddenly?
It's really odd.

Comment: Its a bug with Apple. Make sure to add in the feedback reporter on mac so a future version of xcode will compile this properly

Comment: and the bug still persists. Great company, seriously. Thank you.